# Split string function in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

In SOL Server, I get the value for the parameter, `@codeName`, as "1023 - Hydrabad" from ASP.NET.

```
@codeName = "1023 - Hydrabad"
```

I want `Hydrabad` alone. How to split it?

Comment: 4 upvotes for question and answer for a same user in less than 2 mins, it looks like false voting....

Comment: Yeah, something's not right here.

Answer (score 1):

Using `RIGHT()`, `LEN()` and `CHARINDEX()`, you can get the expected output:

```
SELECT TRIM(RIGHT(@codeName, LEN(@codeName) - CHARINDEX('-', @codeName)));
```

Sample execution:

```
DECLARE @codeName AS VARCHAR (100) = '1023 - Hydrabad';
SELECT TRIM(RIGHT(@codeName, LEN(@codeName) - CHARINDEX('-', @codeName)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL Server's SUBSTRING and CHARINDEX functions:

```
DECLARE @codeName VarChar(100)
SET @codeName = '1023 - Hydrabad'
SELECT SUBSTRING(@codeName, CHARINDEX('-', @codeName) + 2, 100)
```

or use appropriate similar .NET methods in your code behind.